# Cross-Platform Development (iOS/Android/Blackberry) on Windows

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cross-platform, native-code

I know this topic has been covered to death here, and I did search before posting this, with none of the answers directly covering this.

I have found multiple solutions for the creation of apps cross-platform; there is the HTML5 + CSS + JS method, using Adobe Air, or just designing it in native code.

My issue revolves around what I've read for iOS so far.
For iOS almost all of what I've found so far, whether it's using RhoStudio or Appcelerator Titanium, seems to require that I have a Mac with OSX first in order to get the SDK -- with the only work around on Windows being running Mac OSX on a secondary HDD or a virtualized environment - which violates TOS.

I've also read that native code will still execute faster/more efficiently than the other methods.

This leads me to a few questions:
1) Is there anything that I have not yet looked up that would be capable of designing the app through multiple platforms, but developed strictly in Windows? Or do they all require to be done with Mac OSX in some way, shape, or form?

2) Is HTML5/CSS/JS even worth looking into, or would performance not be worth it? I recall reading that Facebook's app was originally designed in this method, which is why the performance was bad, but I don't know if there were other factors to it as well.

3) I have found something called Codename One, which so far seems the most promising for cross-compatible development done in Java, but would it really be beneficial? Or would I wind up running into the same issue that I am having with requiring a Mac in the end?

4) Finally: Would it be better to just bite the bullet and purchase a Mac with OSX on it, learn Objective-C, develop it through Native code and then port it to Android/Blackberry?

I know some of these questions have been covered before, but not all of them are up to date - and I know new cross-platform developers have been released since then.
The main thing I'm trying to find is what is the overall best solution to cross development that involves iOS, because most workarounds with Mac seem to void TOS.

I'd appreciate and welcome any available information
- Bitwize

Comment: At some point the code will have to go through XCode, either on your machine or someone else's if you are looking at a hosted solution. No different for Windows.

Comment: So I'm still going to require a Mac at one point or another then (because XCode is only Mac)?

Comment: If you are developing for iOS you are going to have to use the tools and the tools only exist on Mac. If you are concerned about cost, well no one said any activity would be cheap, especially if you are keeping up with the newest mobile devices. There are things you can do to minimize it (buy refurbished or used) but in the end its a cost of doing business.

Comment: I understand that it wouldn't be cheap, and I've decided to go through Native code instead. It just bothers me that they only make the tools for it on a Mac instead of allowing it to be developed cross-compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends upon what you want to develop and who you want to develop for. It you want high quality, cutting edge, buy a Mac and go with native development for iOS. You may want to support other environments with HTML5.

Yes, HTML5 has a performance and usability hit, but it may be acceptable to your audience and budget.

I wrote an ebook about this available, even available to people with windows machines:) http://digital-possibilities.com/mobile-development-frameworks-overview/

Comment: I would up-vote this, but apparently I can't because I'm a new user and I don't have 15 reputation.

It looks like I'm stuck getting a Mac. 
It's really frustrating that they would do that. It's bad enough they charge $99/year to be a developer AND take 30% from the sales of each app, but they also make their kits proprietary to only Apple users. 

At least other brands make it available for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: @Bitwize  As a professional developer $99 is a lot less than 2 hours of my billing time (and is a tax deduction) so if I can't raise that money once a year then I have bigger problems - like starvation. As for the 30% .. I'd suggest that you would pay a similar amount of money if you were providing the global hosting, e-commerce and marketing (via iTunes) services that Apple provides.

Comment: @PeterM I'm not saying I disagree with the 30% cost at all, I'm just saying that it bothers me that Apple decided to not only make their tools proprietary to their system, but they also charge the yearly developer fee ON TOP of the 30%. The other companies all make their development kits cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

Codename One has a build server with hosted macs on the cloud, you can develop your app on windows only.